# Java pre-installed in Windows and Linux?

Tags: java, windows, linux, macos

I know that Java is pre-installed in Mac OS X but i wonder if it is pre-installed in Windows XP, Vista, 7 and all Linux distros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java isn't preinstalled in any Windows version (OEM not included - depends on the manufacturer then).

I think it is not common in Linux distributions at all, but I don't want to make a general statement about ALL distros here ;-)

Comment: Why? I mean, it's free, not such a big problem, is it?

Comment: but then the users (that aren´t that skilled with Java) have to install Java first before they can use my Java applications. it could disencourage them to use it.

Comment: Java is not pre-installed on OSX 10.7 and above.  If you try to run a Java app, it will bring up an install prompt, and will install Java 6.  This isn't expected to last forever.  Oracle has taken over all distribution of Java 7 going forward.  At this point the popular method of distributing java applications seems to be bundling the JRE with your app.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora Linux comes with [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page), an open source Java.

Answer (score 0):

Some Linux versions I experienced comes with old versions of Java JDK (so you must take care developing for these distributions!) or with an alternative version of the compiler: Gnu Compiler Java (GCJ).

About the virtual machine, I've just seen the JVM in Windows and Linux, provided by Sun.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the vast majority of PCs come with the Sun JRE installed. There was a bit of a law suite between Microsoft and Sun (my employer, now a wholly owned subsidiary of Oracle).

The "6-open" OpenJDK is a backport of the GPLed JDK7. General purpose distros should include it, but of course with Linux you are fighting with package management.

Comment: This is true in many cases if it comes from a vendor but never as part of an operating system install.

Comment: Not on a CD from Microsoft, no.

Comment: (But the statement about the vast majority of PCs is, I believe, true and not in anyway misleasing.)

Comment: I believe Java was preloaded in Windows prior to the lawsuit. It is not true anymore.

Comment: @hfontanez Microsoft jview was, IIRC, included in Microsoft Windows. At around the time of this question the Sun/Oracle JRE was included by most big manufactures in the big bundle of "crapware" that still gets added to PCs. However, for many years the suggested way of distributing the JRE is as a private installation within the software that uses it.