# Is Java Virtual Machine starts before user logged in to windows?

Tags: java, windows, service, jvm, autostart

Is Java Virtual Machine starts before user logged in or it's start after boot windows.?

Comment: It starts when you run a java program. And each program runs in its own VM. It shuts down when all threads in it are Daemon threads.

Comment: Java isn't preinstalled in any Windows version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163795/java-pre-installed-in-windows-and-linux . So the answer is: in general no. Of course: You can configure you computer to have a JVM started by the OS prior to logging in (a JVM is started if a Java program is started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you start a java program, a new instance of the Java Virtual machine is started.  It stops when the program ends.

In the case of a java applet, the browser will invoke the virtual machine itself.

Answer (score 1):

When a Java application starts, a runtime jvm instance is born. When the application completes, the instance dies. If you start four Java applications at the same time, on the same computer, using the same concrete implementation, you'll get four Java virtual machine instances. Each Java application runs inside its own Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

JVM starts when it's required, in other words as soon as you need an environment to run your Java code, meaning when you start your application.

Try googling for "when JVM starts", it should yield a lot of results which address this question (in Java and also for other languages using JVM). For example [this page](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm.html). Look for "The lifetime of a Java Virtual Machine".

Answer (score 0):

In Windows "Java Virtual Machine" is simply "java.exe" executable.

It will start whey you will start it - manually, by putting it to autorun or by creating Windows Service.

It is the same as any other background application.